# How to use cell address as a parameter of Range()?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template file that I will use to populate more files and I need to hide some rows according to what its selected, but at the same time I can't hide other rows. I can do it well if the data stay the same size all the time, but the file will be increasing and decreasing depending on the information.

I have a range of values in Column C. What I tried to do is to look for the cell value that contains "Pack" (It will be same for all files). From that cell that contains "Pack" (let's assume that is at C8 now, but can be in C30 in other file) I need to start looking for values that are not equal to the one that I have from a droplist (rowing) and hide the rows.

Maybe better explained, also I tried to do was to assign a variable that will hold the value of the droplist and just look for values that was not equal and simply hide it. Then do a .Find() to find the "Pack" word. Once it was found, get the cell address. Finally take that address and use it as a parameter in Range() as yo can see in the code that I wrote: For Each cell In Range("packR:C5") and I know that is very wrong because I can't pass that.

```
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim pack As Range


    rowing = Range("A2").Value

    Set pack = Range("C1:C12").Find("Pack")
    Set packA = Range(pack.Address)

    Set packR = packA

        For Each cell In Range("packR:-end point here")
          cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
       If cell.Value <> rowing Then
          cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
   Next
```

I have very little vba background but with research I can understand a few. Basically the goal is to ignore all the rows in top of "Pack" and start looking from "Pack" (That need to have a cell address) to the end of the excel file. The biggest issue is to take that cell address and use it as parameter to the Range ("":"").

Comment: Couple things. 1) When using `Find`, you want to test if something was actually found, i.e. `If Not pack Is Nothing Then`. 2) You don't need to use `Address` here. If something is found, then `pack` is equivalent to `Range(pack.Address)`. 3) What is the `"packR:C5"` - rows, columns?

Comment: @BigBen "packR was my intent to be the starting point of the Range("":""). Ignore the C5 I forgot to update it. But packR will be the assumption that the program found it at C8, following as: Range("C8": "-end point here-").

Comment: Yes you've defined 3 variables to be the same thing. What does "I can't pass that" mean?

Comment: Can you remove it from your code then please? Do you mean from C8 to the last value in column C?

Comment: @SJR I really don't know what is happening with the sets and all that, I just google a lot of pages and try to get it run. Im just assumming that the program found '"Pack" at C8 for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this. Note the comment about specifying the other parameters of [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find).

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim rowing As Variant
    rowing = ws.Range("A2").Value

    Dim pack As Range
    Set pack = ws.Range("C1:C12").Find("Pack") '<--- you should specify the other parameters of Find

    Dim lastCell As Range
    Set lastCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)

    If Not pack Is Nothing Then '<--- tests to see if pack was found
        Dim cell As Range

        For Each cell In ws.Range(pack, lastCell)
            If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = (cell.Value <> rowing)
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
   `End(xlUp)` will not find the true last row if rows are already hidden. To get around this, here are two options:

1. Unhide all rows after finding "Pack".

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim rowing As Variant
    rowing = ws.Range("A2").Value

    Dim pack As Range
    Set pack = ws.Range("C1:C12").Find("Pack") '<--- you should specify the other parameters of Find

    If Not pack Is Nothing Then '<--- tests to see if pack was found
        ws.UsedRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False '<--- unhide all rows so as to find the last cell properly

        Dim lastCell As Range
        Set lastCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)

        Dim cell As Range

        For Each cell In ws.Range(pack, lastCell)
            If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = (cell.Value <> rowing)
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

2. Use an alternate way of finding the last cell:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim rowing As Variant
    rowing = ws.Range("A2").Value

    Dim pack As Range
    Set pack = ws.Range("C1:C12").Find("Pack") '<--- you should specify the other parameters of Find

    Dim lastCell As Range
    Set lastCell = GetLastCell(ws, 3)

    If Not pack Is Nothing Then '<--- tests to see if pack was found
        Dim cell As Range

        For Each cell In ws.Range(pack, lastCell)
            If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = (cell.Value <> rowing)
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub


Private Function GetLastCell(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal colNum As Long = 1) As Range

    With ws
        Dim lastCell As Range
        Set lastCell = .Columns(colNum).Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Cells(1, colNum), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False)

        If lastCell Is Nothing Then
            Set lastCell = .Cells(1, colNum)
        End If
    End With

    Set GetLastCell = lastCell
End Function
```

Comment: BigBen it works when I change the drop list two times, in the third time, start hiding all the rows up to the top. I don't know how to post a picture to maybe explain better.

Comment: It's because rows are hidden so finding the last row won't work that way..  I'll edit

Comment: Excellent @BigBen, I used the first attempt of Unhide all the rows before finding "Pack" and works very good.

Thank you a lot!